# How are multiple plots in Pydroid 3 made, each in separate windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pydroid

I'm using a matplotlib.pyplot program in Pydroid 3 on a Samsung device. I find i can make a plot of a single graph, but in my program I'd like to make several plots each in a different window. (I've got Kivy and PyQt5 installed.) This works fine on a laptop but when on the Samsung phone it only makes the first plot. How do i get it to show the remainder of the plots?

Thank you for any help.
N